# How to find printer status?

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-export

I try to write a code  for finding status of a printer to print crystal reports which are in pdf format. I have following doughts:

1. How can I fire the code after click the print button in crystal report? Is there any events(lick click) to check the printer staus?
2. What are the properties change when printer in different modes like lid open, no paper, lidopen and no paper, swtch off, switch on, warmup  ect.? what are the numeric values it exactly returns? and is there any changes in return values for different catagery printers(hp laser printes, canon ect..)?
3. How can I display the message "Success" after successful printing of a report?

Pls, Clarify any one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) with the [Win32_Printer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394363%28VS.85%29.aspx) class to query printer information.

There is also [Win32_PrintJob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394370%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), which you could enumerate to determine when a given job completes.  The `Status` property may give you additional granularity on printer status.  You can monitor creation and deletion of these objects - that would give you new and completed job info.

Other printer classes listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a [ObjectQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhttbe39.aspx). "Select * from Win32_PrintJob". Then you have to use [ManagementObjectSearche](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3x6at5a0.aspx)r and ManagementObjectCollection to get the count of items in printqueue.

you can use "SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer" to get printer status